# VSTO "warmup" setting; Does Outlook think the add-in loaded faster?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, vsto

I've [read that Outlook disables](http://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle11150.aspx) add-ins that take too long to load. That's not usually the case with mine, but I think it's happened on occasion for a couple customers.

I recently discovered the [warmup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) VSTO setting:

> A value that indicates that the .NET
>   Framework and Visual Studio Tools for Office [VSTO] runtime load before an
>   add-in loads and reduce the perceived time to load an add-in. Set the
>   Warmup entry to 1, and use it in conjunction with the LoadBehavior
>   entry to reduce the load time for Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013
>   add-ins that are deployed by using Windows Installer (.msi). This
>   registry key cannot be set by using ClickOnce.

I'm not sure if that "perceived time" applies to Outlook, or only the user. Does anyone know if this reduces how long Outlook thinks the add-in took to load? Or is it still timing the whole process, .NET and VSTO runtimes included?

Comment: This setting has now disappeared from the MSDN article you have linked to. Do you know if it is still working?

Comment: You're right, it's gone from recent versions of the article. I'm not sure if it's still necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warmup key forces Outlook to preload the .Net run-time. This way it will be loaded by the time Outlook starts the timer to calculate your addin's startup time and you will not (supposedly) be punished for having to load a couple hundred megabytes worth of dlls simply for the pleasure of writing your code in .Net.